# Turn off popup dialog once clicked

Tags: android, dialog, rate

I'm using this [code](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater) to create a popup dialog in my home activity to ask user to rate my app, the codes work fine, however when users choose the option "No Thanks", the dialog should not show again.

However when the app is reopened, my homeActivity reloads, everything in it is reset, so despite this

```
editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
editor.commit();
```

the dialog will show again, is there anyway I can store the boolean value when the activity is reloaded?

```
public static class AppRater {

    private final int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;
    private final int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 7;

    public void app_launched(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        // Increment launch counter
        long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
        editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

        // Get date of first launch
        Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 0);
        if (date_firstLaunch == 0) {
            date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
            editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
        }

                    // i just use this to test the dialog instantly
            showRateDialog(mContext, editor);



        // Wait at least n days before opening
        if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch + 
                    (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
                showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
            }
        }

        editor.commit();
    }   

    public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate MyApp");

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setText("We see that you have been using MyApp well. Would you like to rate us?");
        tv.setWidth(240);
        tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
        ll.addView(tv);

        Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
        b1.setText("Rate MyApp");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + mContext.getPackageName());
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                  mContext.startActivity(goToMarket); // playstore installed
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { // open website if not
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + mContext.getPackageName())));
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });        
        ll.addView(b1);

        Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
        b2.setText("Remind me later");
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b2);


        Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
        b3.setText("No, thanks");
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rated = true;
                if (editor != null) {
                    editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b3);

        dialog.setContentView(ll);        
        dialog.show();    
    }
}
// http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice problem. I think the reason is, that you commit the `editor` at the end of method `app_launched`, and the button press in the dialog happens some time later, so when you do this `editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true)`, the `editor` is already commited and thus your entry is not saved in the preferences.

If you need help on how to change your code to fix this, let me know in a comment.

**EDIT - Some code**

First, do not pass the editor to your `showRateDialog` method, so change method signature to:

```
public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext)
```

Second, in your `onClick` method, create a new Editor, write the flag and commit.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    rated = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
    // create editor, write stuff and commit, all in one line.
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("dontshowagain", true).commit();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Yes please, in fact I have tried to set another boolean value and test if that value is false, then i wont call showRateDialog(), but it still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my codes like you suggested, but the dialog still load after I exit the app and use it again, btw I called this class in onCreate method from homeActivity

`AppRater.showRateDialog(this);`

Comment: And after the dialog showed up, you clicked "No, thanks" and when you start the App again, the dialog still shows?

Comment: sorry it was my bad, I should've called `AppRater.app_launched(this)` instead, but now the dialog won't even open

Answer (score 1):

Ridicully is correct. Use this code instead and open a new editor:

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rated = true;
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorNew = prefs.edit();
        editorNew.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
        editorNew.commit();

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Then clean up the `showRateDialog` by removing the editor parameter. Remember that the code of the listeners are called long after the methods setting them up has returned.